# Wrong result in a simple ipython script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I defined a simple function that operates on 1st and 3rd rows of a 3x3 matrix:

```
In [1]: from numpy import *    
     from sympy import Symbol
 
In [2]: def ifsin(mat): 
     mat[2,:]+=1
     mat[0,:]=mat[0,:]/pow(mat[2,:],mat[2,:]>0)
     return mat
 
In [3]:Ay=Symbol('Ay')
     By=Symbol('By')
     q=array([[Ay,-10 ,By],[0,0.4,1],[-1 ,-1, -1]])
     q
 
Out[3]:
 
 array([[Ay, -10, By],
        [0, 0.4, 1],
        [-1, -1, -1]], dtype=object)
 
In [4]:V=ifsin(q)
        q
 
Out[4]: array([[Ay, -10.0, By],
        [0, 0.4, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)
```

Why was updated 3rd row of matrix q?

Also if I eval following:

```
In [5]:M=ifsin(V)
       q
     
Out[5]: array([[Ay, -10.0, By],
            [0, 0.4, 1],
            [1, 1, 1]], dtype=object)
```

Again 3rd row of q is updated!!

I tried this script on "Computable" (ipad app) and ipython notebook on ubuntu 14.04 (python 2.7.6) with the same results

Thanks in advance for your help.

updated…

I changed my function to:

```
def ifsin(m): 
  return vstack([m[0,:]/pow(m[2,:]+1,(m[2,:]+1)>0),m[1,:],m[2,:]+1])
```

And now all works fine. Thanks!!

Comment: Uhm, because matrix row indices are zero based, so ` mat[2,:]+=1` reads as "add one to evey element in 3rd row"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are literally asking for that update on this line:

```
mat[2,:]+=1
```

In numpy syntax, this means "update row 2 of the array named `mat` by incrementing each value by 1".

Comment: Yes Oliver, that line says that, so only **must** update the array that is input in function `ifsin`, and not update another array

Comment: @OscarCampo and which array are you passing to that function then? Please have a look at [this famous SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference). Then when you understand it, and you want to solve it, you could pass a copy of `q` to `ifsin`: `V = ifsin(q.copy())`. Or change the logic in the function, either way works.

Comment: Also, you might want to remember that the reason `q` still gets updated in that last call to `ifsin` is because `V` and `q` (and eventually `M`) all refer to the same object. These are merely aliases, bound to the same object in memory (which you can check by asking for their `id`).